# sinon server.autoRespond

Tags: javascript, ajax, karma-jasmine, sinon

I'm learning testing, so I construct this simple example, using karma,karma-jasmine and sinon.js:
I have got an ajax Request, on success it sets an global variable.
With the sinon fakeServer I fake the respond, everything is fine if I fire the respond with the sinon.server.respond() function manually.
But changing the sinon fakeServer to autoRespond = true, don't word as expected. The test ist failing because the global variable is still undefined. It seems for me that the fakeRequest don't answer when set to autoRespond = true.
Has anyone an suggestion why? Thanks for any help.
Code to test:

```
var requestResult;  // global variable


function loadFirstData () {

  var request = $.ajax( {
                          url     : "/rest/first/",
                          type    : "GET",
                          timeout : 5000,
                          dataType: "json"
                      } );

  request.done( function ( data ) {
      requestResult = data;
  } );

  request.fail( function ( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      console.error( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
      console.error( "Object: ", jqXHR );
  } );
}
```

The test:

```
describe( 'Ajax requests', function () {
  var xhr;

  beforeEach(function() {
    xhr = sinon.fakeServer.create();

    // this doesn't work
    //xhr.autoRespond = true;

    xhr.respondWith(
        'GET',
        '/rest/first/',
        function (request) {
            request.respond(
                200,
                { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                '{ "returnValue": 20.13 }'
            );
        }
    );
    xhr.respondWith(
        'GET',
        'rest/second/',
        function (request) {
            request.respond(
                200,
                { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                '{ "returnValue": 3333 }'
            );
        }
    );


  });

  afterEach(function() {
    xhr.restore();
  });

  it( 'should get first data', function () {
    loadFirstData();

    // this works
    xhr.respond();

    expect( requestResult ).toEqual( { "returnValue": 20.13 } );


  } );

} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. :)
The sinon fake-server doesn't answer the request immediately but with a short delay. So I have to make the jasmine-tests asynchronously using the done() Funktion.
So the following code works:

```
describe( 'Ajax requests', function () {
  var xhr;

  // beforeEach get the jasmine done as argument
  beforeEach(function(done) {
    xhr = sinon.fakeServer.create();

    // autoRespond is set
    xhr.autoRespond = true;

    xhr.respondWith(
      'GET',
      '/rest/first/',
      function (request) {
        request.respond(
            200,
            { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            '{ "returnValue": 20.13 }'
        );
      }
    );
    xhr.respondWith(
      'GET',
      'rest/second/',
      function (request) {
        request.respond(
            200,
            { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            '{ "returnValue": 3333 }'
        );
      }
    );

    // starts the tests
    done();

  });

  afterEach(function() {
    xhr.restore();
  });

  // the asynchronous test get the jasmie done as argument, as well
  it( 'should get first data', function (done) {
    loadFirstData();

    // delays the expectations check
    setTimeout( function() {
      expect( requestResult ).toEqual( { "returnValue": 20.13 } );

      // says jasmine the test is finished
      done();
    }, 500);

  } );

} );
```

Comment: Sorry but it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The Sinon docs state that `autoRespond` is not suitable for tests for the reason you discovered.

I ended up implementing a `respondImmediately` property on the `fakeServer` that will synchronously respond to any request. This just got merged into the project a few weeks ago (v1.14.0), but if you update to the newest version you should be able to get it. [Check out the docs here.](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer)

Instead of setting the `autoRespond` property to true, set the `respondImmediately` property to true. You can then remove all of the async `done` calls and remove the `setTimeout` wrappers around your expectations. Hope this helps unclutter your tests!